# Не могу получить доступ к сайту на Laravel, запущенному в Docker

Tags: laravel, docker

Впервые работаю с докером, заворачиваю в него сайт на ларавеле (php + laravel + postgresql). И не получается получить к нему доступ.
Делаю по инструкции https://www.twilio.com/blog/get-started-docker-laravel и всё нормально до момента *"Once this is completed, navigate to http://localhost:8080/ which should display the default Laravel welcome page."* У меня в браузере вместо этого *"Unable to connect"*. При этом просто "http://localhost" успешно показывает дефолтную страницу апача.

Контейнеры нормально создаются и стартуют

**sudo docker-compose up -d --build**

**sudo docker-compose exec php-apache /bin/bash**

Я могу зайти в контейнер, стартовать ларавел и пересобрать базу

**php artisan serve**

**php artisan migrate:refresh**

Значит контейнер имеет доступ и к веб серверу в контейнере, и к внешнему серверу БД postgres (пока что на БД в контейнере не перенастраивал). А вот 8000 порт недоступен.
Видимо проблема в портах, и я не понимаю, как её исправить. В итоге мне нужно получать доступ к этому веб серверу по 80, 8000 и 6001 порту (последний - веб сокеты).

Что мне нужно исправить?

Структура каталогов:

```
docker 
  apache
    ¬ default.conf
  databases
  php
    ¬ Dockerfile
  src
    ¬ (тут копия рабочего сайта)
  ¬ docker-compose.yml
```

**default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName WebServer
   DocumentRoot /var/www/WebServer/public
   <Directory /var/www/WebServer>
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt update && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/WebServer

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    database:
        image: postgres
        container_name: database
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1111111
            POSTGRES_DB: websocket
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'

    php-apache:
        container_name: php-apache
        build:
            context: ./php
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/WebServer
            - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
        depends_on:
            - database
```

**UPDATE1:**
Я добавил порты,

```
 ports:
    - '8080:80'
    - '8000:8000'
    - '6001:6001'
```

теперь после запуска вебсокетов в консоли видно, что клиенты успешно подключаются. Но доступа к админке вебсокетов http://192.168.1.61:8080/laravel-websockets нет, и отправка POST сообщений http://192.168.1.61:8080/telephonyCall для сервера веб-сокета возвращает 404.

Comment: Вам не нужно запускать ваш сервер через artisan, дайте Апачу возможность обрабатывать входящие запросы, открыв ваш сайт на порту 8080, который и так уже выведен наружу для сервиса Апач. Там же об этом так и написано - Once this is completed, navigate to http://localhost:8080/ which should display the default Laravel welcome page.

Comment: Не нужно запускать? Но без докера же запускаю. Я делаю php artisan serve и php artisan websockets:serve. После этоо у меня есть доступ к дашборду вебсокетов http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets. Это без докера. А с докером, если открыть http://192.168.1.61:8080, то получаю 404 от ларавела (это нормально, у меня нет такого маршрута в нём). А если открыть http://192.168.1.61:8080/laravel-websockets, то получаю просто Not Found от браузера. В общем, я полностью запутался, что мне нужно делать. Что запускать, что настраивать, на какой порт стучаться.

Comment: Пройдите шаг за шагом то, что описано в статье, добейтесь того же результата, а уже ПОСЛЕ изменяйте на то что вам нужно.

Comment: Сделал. Но статья заканчивается на том, что там просто поднимается ларавел. У меня это уже сделано. А вот с сокетами проблема. Вернее, такое ощущение,ч то с сокетами как раз проблемы нет, а есть с доступом в админку сокетов по простому get запросу. Я не понимаю, что не так.

Answer (score 1):

Если запустить команду

```
  php artisan serve
```

то он стартует на локалхосте.
Если

```
  php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.61
```

то будет доступен извне (тут 192.168.1.61 - это ip адрес машины, на которой запускаем). Но контейнер использует собственную сеть и 192.168.1.61 для него - это "за пределами сети", поэтому стартовать артизан не может.

Чтобы страница http://192.168.1.61:8080/laravel-websockets была доступна, нужно запускать так:

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте sail - замечательная обертка докера для локальной разработки
https://youtu.be/TbvJvbHErcA мой пример с myslq

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)